# Подсказка в поле для ввода(Подстроить маску)

Tags: javascript

есть код, который дает возможность при клике на кнопку добавлять маску в конце в поле для ввода, вот — https://jsfiddle.net/mwLLe4pp/
при вводе цифр, то все норм, плюсик становиться должным образом(в конце), но стоит ввести разные буквы+цифры или пробелы, то все рушиться(плюс отходит слишком далеко от текста).. в частности, это наблюдается у букв: i, l etc. как я понял, это зависит от ширины буквы. Так вот, как все это более правильно рассчитать?

```
var text   = document.getElementById('txt');
var syntax = document.getElementById('syntax');

function action(){
    var str = "";
    for(var  i = 0; i < text.value.length*2; i++){
        str += " ";
    }
    syntax.value = str + "+";
}
action();
```

Comment: А фиксированную ширину текста использовать нельзя? Например, `font-family: monospace`, тогда все нормально будет

Comment: Если фиксированную ширину все-так нельзя использовать, то можно адаптировать [это](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/measuring-the-length-of-a-string-in-pixels-using-javascript/) - вместо добавления пробелов просто смещаем положение плюса на найденную длину строки. Если такой вариант устроит, то оформить ответом смогу несколько позже

Comment: устроит, спасибо! жду))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Идея взята [отсюда](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/measuring-the-length-of-a-string-in-pixels-using-javascript/): копируем текст в элемент, который меняет свои размеры в зависимости от текста. Дальше находим размеры этого элемента и сдвигаем наш "плюсик" на нужное кол-во пикселей.

**-1-** Создаем элемент, который будет использован для определения размеров текста:

```
<span id="ruler"></span>
```

и задаем ему стили:

```
#ruler {
    visibility: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: absolute;
}
```

`visibility: hidden;` используется для того, чтобы наш вспомогательный элемент, с одной стороны, не был виден, а с другой стороны - для того, чтобы он в зависимости от контента менял свои размеры (чего нельзя было бы добиться при `display: none`)

`white-space: nowrap;` используется для того, чтобы весь текст был в одну строку (без переносов). Соответственно при получении размеров элемента мы получим ширину всего текста, а не его части.

`position: absolute;` используем для того, чтобы наш элемент никаким образом не влиял на расположение остального контента.

**-2-** Определяем функцию вычисления длины текста:

Для того, чтобы определить длину текста (в пикселях, а не в символах), необходимо вставить наш текст в созданный раннее элемент и получить его `offsetWidth`.

Для этого есть несколько способов. Мы воспользуемся методом, предложенным в статье: определим для строк функцию `visualLength`, которая будет совершать все необходимые действия:

```
String.prototype.visualLength = function() {
    var ruler = document.getElementById('ruler');
    ruler.innerHTML = this;
    return ruler.offsetWidth;
}
```

Теперь получить длину текста можно будет так: `"mystring".visualLength()`

**-3-** Переместим "плюсик" на нужное место:

Поскольку мы теперь знаем длину текста, то сдвинув наш "плюсик" на нужное кол-во пикселей мы получим желаемый результат.

Вопрос только - как сдвигать? Поскольку у вас для "плюсика" используется `input` то сдвигать его изменяя `left` не получится - `input`, его содержащий, визуально будет выделяться. Для того, чтобы `input` никуда не съезжал, можно менять его `padding-left` - тогда и `input` на месте, и текст сдвинется.

Но мы сделаем немного по-другому: для `syntax` используем `div`. Тогда можно будет смело менять его `left`-положение и при большом отступе он не исчезнет где-то за пределами элемента.

Таким образом мы получили нашу измененную функцию:

```
function action() {
    var text   = document.getElementById('txt');
    var syntax = document.getElementById('syntax');
    syntax.style.left = text.value.visualLength() + 'px';
}
```

**-4-** Компонуем все вместе:

Код мы получили, но толку от него пока еще мало: при изменении текста наш "плюсик" со временем скроется под текстом.

Почему? Ведь вроде все же сделали правильно?

А дело в том, что при вычислении длины текста в пикселях мы не учитывали размер и стиль шрифта. Т.е. в нашем элементе `ruler` использовался один шрифт, а в `input` был использован другой шрифт.

Поэтому необходимо либо программно, либо через `css` задать этим элементам одинаковые стили:

```
input, #ruler, #syntax {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Arial;
}
```

Тогда ширина текста в одном элементе будет равна ширине текста в другом элементе.

**Результат**

В итоге мы получили следующее:

```js
String.prototype.visualLength = function() {
    var ruler = document.getElementById('ruler');
    ruler.innerHTML = this;
    return ruler.offsetWidth;
}

function action() {
    var text   = document.getElementById('txt');
    var syntax = document.getElementById('syntax');
    syntax.style.left = text.value.visualLength() + 'px';
}
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].onclick = action;
action();
```

```css
#wrap{
    position: relative;
    height: 38px;
}
#txt {
    background: transparent;
}
input {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #A5C7FE;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 500px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    outline: none;
    padding: 5px;
}
#syntax{
    position: absolute;
    color: #bbb;
    padding: 5px;
}
input, #ruler, #syntax {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Arial;
}
#ruler {
    visibility: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <span id="ruler"></span>
    <div id="syntax">+</div>
 <input type="text" id="txt" value="0000" />
</div>
<button>ACTION</button><br>
```

Comment: Пример тогда же кода на jsfiddle [ЗДЕСЬ](https://jsfiddle.net/mwLLe4pp/1/)

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!