# OOP в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ооп

Есть строка "маяк", нужно заменить кириллицу латиницей, чтобы в итоге получился "majak".

Сам код в виде
`"маяк". transliterate(); //должно вернуть "majak"`

Как реализовать данную функцию и как будет называться при этом `transliterate()`
?

Comment: А как вы видите ответ на этот вопрос?

Comment: Сделать `"маяк".translation()` можно через прототипы. Пример как сделать можно посмотреть в моем [ответе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/413842/5079) А вот логику придется самому придумать, т.к. иначе это работа за автора

Comment: @BOPOH, [пример «логики» по госту](http://javascript.ru/forum/misc/27347-nadezhnyjj-dvukhstoronnijj-translit.html#post168115)

Comment: Спасибо большое, разобрался.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, не нашел в госте ни одной строчки кода, особенно на javascript. Так же на нашел алгоритма, одни правила преобразования, которые алгоритмом не являются

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, кстати, там пример не совсем по госту: вместо Ц рекомендуется употреблять C перед буквами I, E, Y, J, а в остальных случаях CZ.

Comment: @BOPOH, транслитерация (т.е., «логика») в соответствии с [гостом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0_%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B9#.D0.93.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.83.D0.B4.D0.B0.D1.80.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B2.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B4.D0.B0.D1.80.D1.82.D1.8B). по приведённой ранее ссылке — реализация на *javascript*.

Comment: @BOPOH, точность реализации я не проверял. но, в принципе, гостов было несколько (см. ссылку на википедийную статью).

Comment: @BOPOH, изложите, пожалуйста, ваши предложения в виде ответа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эта операция назвается "транслитерация". Есть достаточно много реализаций, например:

https://github.com/xguest/iso_9_js/blob/master/translit.js

"Навесить" всем строчкам ее можно через расширение прототипа:

```
String.prototype.transliterate = function () {
    return translit(this, 5);
};

"маяк".transliterate();
```

Comment: Мне не сама функция нужна была, а логика построения прототипа.

Comment: @Sh.Khachatryan ну это и есть вся логика.

Comment: Я понял. Спасибо большое)

Comment: @Sh.Khachatryan а, не увидел вашего "спасибо, разобрался" в комментах ). Если вы нашли ответ на вопрос - приводите его здесь, пожалуйста. Вопросы с "все, разобрался" - не слишком полезны для тех, кто придет сюда из гугла.

Comment: Ок. Я тут просто впервые. Сейчас отдельным постом напишу что получилось.

Comment: @Sh.Khachatryan отлично. только не отдельным вопросом, а еще одним ответом - чуть ниже есть кнопка. кстати, тут за ответы на собственные вопросы медальки дают (хотя их ценность сомнительна :)

Answer (score 1):

**К чему я пришел:**

В итоге мой код получился такой:

`var item = {city:['Vashington','Moskva','Erevan']};`

```
var trans = function() {
    var
        rus = "щ   ш  ч  ц  ю  я  ё  ж  ъ  ы  э  а б в г д е з и й к л м н о п р с т у ф х ь".split(/ +/g),
        eng = "shh sh ch cz yu ya yo zh `` y' e` a b v g d e z i j k l m n o p r s t u f x `".split(/ +/g)
    ;
    return function(engToRus) {
        var x,
        text = this;
        for(x = 0; x < rus.length; x++) {
            text = text.split(engToRus ? rus[x] : eng[x]).join(engToRus ? eng[x] : rus[x]);
            text = text.split(engToRus ? rus[x].toUpperCase() : eng[x].toUpperCase()).join(engToRus ? eng[x].toUpperCase() : rus[x].toUpperCase());
        }
        return text;
    }
};

Object.prototype.transliterate = trans();

for(var i = 0; i < Object.keys(item.city).length; i++) {
    console.log(item.city[i].transliterate());
}
```

P.S. Спасибо за ответы.